# How to tile the specific window s or app on the desktop

Tags: vbscript

I searched the web and found a vb script to tile windows on the desktop. But I want to tile specific windows or apps. For example, if I open three images in Paint and one Excel file, I only want to show Paint apps tiling on the desktop.

I changed my code as suggested by Dai, however all windows are tiling. 
There is another question. In my code I filtered "Untitled -Paint". However if I opened image, there would be "filename  -Paint" . How can I get them?
Here is the code so far:

```
   Option Explicit 

   Dim oWS, oShell
   Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
   Set oWS=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   
   Dim App
   App="Untitled - Paint"

    If oWS.AppActivate(App) then

     else
       WScript.Sleep 500   
       oWS.SendKeys "% x"               
      End if

      oShell.TileVertically   
       WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Simply minimize all non-Paint windows first, then perform the `TileVertically` operation.

Comment: @Dai I don't know how to get the non-Paint windows first. Would you have example code or link for the reference. Thanks.

Comment: @Dai, I changed my code as your suggestion, however all windows are tiling. There is another question. In my code I filtered "Untitled -Paint". However if I opened image, there would be "filename -Paint" . How can I get them?